# Conditional rendering in NextJS app with Next-Auth

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, oauth, next-auth

I'm building a small SAAS app for the first time. I've been programming for some time but not professionally, so **my knowledge on how to properly do this is kinda bad**.

I have an Nextjs app where I use  Next-Auth for the authentication. To my "issue", when signed out - I want the user to see the landingpage and a navbar with:

- Pricing
- Testimonials
- Use Cases
- About
- Sign In

But when logged in, the user should see some kind of dashboard and a navbar with:

- My sites
- (Profile Icon)

  - Manage sites
  - Manage profile
  - Billing
  - Signout

Right now im rendering like this in my navbar for example (code scaled down):

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import React from 'react'
import SignOutButton from './signout'
import { options } from '../api/auth/[...nextauth]/options'
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"
import SignInButton from './signin'

const Navbar = async () => {

  const session = await getServerSession(options)

  return (
      <div className="navbar-end">
        {session ? <SignOutButton /> : <SignInButton />}
      </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

Cant I do this on a higher level in layout.tsx or page.tsx? Then just add a parameter or such to the child files?

Thanks!